# How to thermally insulate beaker glass on hotplate?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, heat, mixtures

I bought a magnetic stirrer with a hot plate almost identical to [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07KJZRMWQ).

I am trying an experiment where I need to heat the beaker/mixture to about 100 degrees C. However the mixture/beaker is losing a lot of heat to the environment, especially when being stirred and it *needs* to be stirred.

I tried using the included thermometer but the algorithm seems to be imperfect because while trying to heat the mixture to my desired temperature the apparatus would heat the hotplate to such high temperatures that the bottom of the mixture starts boiling even when stirring at high speeds and this is suboptimal as the mixture becomes a gel at a certain not-to-high temperature and I need to avoid that.

Since I'm quite new to this, is there any way to insulate the beaker or in some other way prevent heat loss without heating the room to 100 deg C?

Comment: It sounds like you should take a page out of the culinary world and use a [bain-marie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bain-marie). You can stay below or just at 100 °C pretty reliably with it.

Comment: Which is more important, not overheating or heating evenly? It is far from obvious that *insulating* the vessel will make either better. Use a water bath around the vessel to prevent both overheating and to give an even heat. heat loss isn't the same problem as getting an even heat distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it to be open or can be closed ?

If the former, the major loses can be due evaporation, keep the opening as small as possible and safe. If there is a wide opening as beakers have, try to put aluminium foil cap freely sitting on the beaker top, if applicable. Or a "watches/clock glass", typically used to cover beakers.

Additionally, try to wrap the beaker by aluminium foil that reflects thermal radiation, leaving just a bottom to be observed. You may try also a foil sandwich with isolation inbetween, like polyurethane foam or some fabric( like wiping/washing fabric for kitchen or floor cleaning or similar ).

If the primary problem is rather undesired overheating, than a water bath is the solution as @nicolausakerneto suggests, eventually isolating all, if still desired.

Comment: It can be closed and I usually put something over the lid, I'll try the foil idea. Is this the usual approach in lab conditions in such cases? I thought there would be some sort of procedure or something else that would give a higher effectiveness.

Comment: It may not be the common need and the lab workers often use DIY approach. At least we did when I was there.

Comment: If the beaker «of interest» has a flat *and dry* outer bottom, than you can put it in a second beaker *of dry and flat* inner bottom, slightly larger in inner diameter than the outer diameter of the inserted beaker.  It isn't perfect, but this «coat» equally shields the inner beaker from air current (e.g., next to the open sash of a fume hood).  The contacting bottom surfaces of the two beakers must be dry, otherwise evaporating water may damage the setup.  *Gentle* heating, of course.

Comment: @Buttonwood I would afraid it may be tight trade off between heating enough the inner beaker and not overheating the bottom of the outer one or heater itself. Unless one has handy a usable metallic plate to put inside.

Comment: @Poutnik .True., immersion of a temperature probe into the inner beaker of the two and dialing up the heating plate to the maximum power indeed is a good approach to shatter the setup by uneven thermal expansion. The gentle increase of temperature mentioned is easier to obtain if you still have an old «flat iron»-type heating plate instead of the ones with a glass surface and proceed slowly (multiple plateaux) over time.

Comment: Getting good, even, contact across the bottom is as important as wrapping the side and covering the top. A thin glass fiber paper (asbestos is good, too), or a sandwich of aluminum against the hotplate plus a thin cotton fabric (like a handkerchief) plus an upper layer of aluminum touching the beaker bottom will help to even out the beaker bottom temp. Glass electrical tape is useful (high temp); big stir bar to sweep the bottom and/or boiling stones to whip the liquid up more.